# foreign or primary keys ORA-02270, i can not insert a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code and it indicates the error ORA-02270

```
    CREATE TABLE SEDE(
    SEDE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    CAMPUS VARCHAR2(50),

    CONSTRAINT PK_SEDE PRIMARY KEY(SEDE)
);

---------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO(
        NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
        SEDE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
        TELEFONO VARCHAR2(10),
        DIRECTOR INT,

        CONSTRAINT PK_DEPARTAMENTO PRIMARY KEY(NOMBRE,SEDE)
);

---------------------------------------------
***HERE IS THE PROBLEM****

CREATE TABLE UBICACION(
    NOMBRE_SEDE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE_DEPTO VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_UBICACION PRIMARY KEY(NOMBRE_SEDE,NOMBRE_DEPTO),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UBICACION FOREIGN KEY(NOMBRE_SEDE) REFERENCES SEDE(SEDE) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UBICACION2 FOREIGN KEY(NOMBRE_DEPTO) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO(NOMBRE) ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```

EDIT: More code to answer a question.

```
CREATE TABLE GRUPO(
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    AREA_CONOCIMIENTO VARCHAR2(50),
    NOMBRE_DEPTO VARCHAR2(50),
    LIDER INT,

    CONSTRAINT PK_GRUPO PRIMARY KEY(NOMBRE,NOMBRE_DEPTO)

);


---------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE PROFESOR(
    DNI INT NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50),
    TITULACION VARCHAR2(50),
    ANIOS_EXP INT,
    GRUPO_PARTICIPA VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT PK_PROFESOR PRIMARY KEY(DNI)

);



ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTO ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DEPARTAMENTO FOREIGN KEY(DIRECTOR) REFERENCES PROFESOR(DNI) ON DELETE CASCADE;

   ** HERE IS PROBLEM TOO***  
    ALTER TABLE GRUPO ADD CONSTRAINT FK_GRUPO FOREIGN KEY(NOMBRE_DEPTO) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO(NOMBRE) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE GRUPO ADD CONSTRAINT FK_GRUPO2 FOREIGN KEY(LIDER) REFERENCES PROFESOR(DNI) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

> Informe de error -
>   ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
>   02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
>   *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
>              gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
>              key constraint in the referenced table.
>   *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
>              catalog view

What do i have to do? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

THIS QUESTION ADDRESSES THE ORIGINAL QUESTION.

The primary key on `departmento` has two parts.  If you want a foreign key relationship, you need to reference both of them:

```
CREATE TABLE UBICACION(
    NOMBRE_SEDE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE_DEPTO VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_UBICACION PRIMARY KEY(NOMBRE_SEDE,NOMBRE_DEPTO),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UBICACION FOREIGN KEY(NOMBRE_SEDE) REFERENCES SEDE(SEDE) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UBICACION2 FOREIGN KEY(NOMBRE_DEPTO, NOMBRE_SEDE) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO(NOMBRE, SEDE) ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f851) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: But "NOMBRE_SEDE" is not a foreign key to the "departamento" table, but to the "sede" table ...

Comment: @RicardoBarros . . . You have defined `sede` as part of the primary key for `departmento`.  You will note that the code works with this change.

Comment: Ok bro, that works, but but I will continue to have the same problem, if you look at the code I added (I edited the post) you will see that when I do the "ALTER TABLE GROUP ADD CONSTRAINT FK_GRUPO ..." the same error continues to appear due to the same problem. And this time I can not use "sede" since it is not in the table as in the other case.

Comment: @RicardoBarros . . . I answered the question you asked.  If you have another question, then ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a second look at your design.  If DEPARTMENTO has a Composite Primary Key (2 columns), a Foreign Key reference to it cannot be for a single column alone -- because the single column alone cannot guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Hi, that design is in a book, I just copy it and when I ran it I realized it did not work: S